# Mongodb TS typings on find doesn't do excess property checking

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

With this Typescript code using latest (6.2) driver for mongodb

```
import { Collection, Db, MongoClient } from "mongodb";


interface MySchema {
    str: string;
    num: number;
  }

  const initializeDbAndCollections = async () => {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    const db = client.db("foodb");
    const coll : Collection<MySchema> = db.collection("myCollection");
    return {
        coll
    }
  };



  const testFind = async () => {
    const { coll } = await initializeDbAndCollections();
    const result = await coll.find({str:"str", num: 5, foo: "bar"}).toArray();//foo should error
    console.log(result);
  }
```

I'm doing a bogus find on the coll collection with a `foo` property that doesn't exist.
TS has a structural (duck typed) type system, but when passing an object litteral to a function, *excess property checking* forbid to add property that don't exist.

The `collection.find` function is typed like this

```
find(filter: Filter<TSchema>, options?: FindOptions): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>;
```

`Filter<TSchema>` is typed like this

```
export declare type Filter<TSchema> = {
    [P in keyof WithId<TSchema>]?: Condition<WithId<TSchema>[P]>;
} & RootFilterOperators<WithId<TSchema>>;
```

It's my understanding that this code should correctly enforce `MySchema` and prevent lookup on property that doesn't exist.
Why is it not the case ?

`coll` is correctly infered as `Collection<MySchema>`